# Вместо "близок кому-то" допустимо ли "близок для кого-то"?

Tags: управление, раздельно-дефис

> Теперь ещё пара шагов – и нас ждёт чудо монументальной живописи –
>   капелла Зенона. Нам ничего не известно об этом святом, кроме того, что
>   **он был чрезвычайно близок для папы Пасхалия**, если приблизительно в период создания мозаик храма создаётся и богато украшенная капелла
>   памяти Зенона, или, как ещё принято называть этого святого, Сан Дзено.

Попутно: *Сан Дзено* не через дефис ли?

Comment: Раскардаш и дежавю в парах: капелла Зенона — капелла памяти Зенона; создания — создаётся; близок — приблизительно; об этом святом — этого святого. И ещё: чудом монументальной живописи названа мозаика или, что ещё смешнее, капелла. Это три боооольшие разницы.

Comment: Всё. Издательство попросило изложить всё то же, но ужав "искусствоведческую парадигму" и цитаты - напрочь изъять. Переходим в разговорную стилистику.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**близкий**
кому-чему и к кому-чему.
1. *кому-чему* (дорогой кому-либо; отвечающий чьим-либо взглядам; непосредственно касающийся).
*Задачи партии близки и понятны массам* (М. И. Калинин).
*...он был чрезвычайно близок папе Пасхалию...*
[**Словарь управления**](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/92/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Капелла Сан Дзено — раздельное написание и написание через дефис встречаются с одинаковой частотностью, выбор сделать практически невозможно.

Comment: О последнем. Тут не по церквям проверять нужно, а по именам; вот Санта-Барбара через дефис же, как и Санта-Клаус...

Comment: Если бы мне пришлось писать, я бы оформила с дефисом.